# Hebrew character issue in DB2 Connect

Tags: database, utf-8, db2, mainframe, db2-connect

I am using DB2 Connect product to catalog the database in AIX server, but the database is in Z/OS environment. When I query the Hebrew character, I am getting the below result.

```
''É ÉñéßÇâéì 7;  
Ââ íéäéîÃè áÇâç ßì éè  
 ÇÑéè Çéã  éâéÉì èÂ-è  
ïãçñâá àÇÑî 
î"Ââ 1996 åëÇî ÉéâåÇî ì  
Ãéé -îÂâ èééñéÇ Ã î âè  
ÀÉÑ ÅÃãî âÃî éìÅÉá
```

Note: If we run the same query in Z/OS environment with Host Code page 424, It is showing proper Hebrew characters. But, If we change the Host Code page to "037 United States", we are getting the above displayed result. Please suggest me your ideas.

```
Result -- > locale -a 
C 
POSIX 
EN_US.UTF-8 
EN_US 
HE_IL.UTF-8 
HE_IL 
Iw_IL.IBM-856 
Iw_IL 
en_US.8859-15 
en_US.ISO8859-1 
en_US.UTF-8 
en_US 
he_IL.UTF-8 
iw_IL.ISO8859-8 
iw_IL 

Result --> locale 

LANG=HE_IL 
LC_COLLATE="HE_IL" 
LC_CTYPE="HE_IL" 
LC_MONETARY="HE_IL" 
LC_NUMERIC="HE_IL" 
LC_TIME="HE_IL" 
LC_MESSAGES="HE_IL" 
LC_ALL=
```

I have queried the hexadecimal value of the Hebrew character in the Z/OS, and I have checked that result with the hexadecimal value of Hebrew character in AIX. Both are having same hexadecimal values. And, AIX version is 7.1 and DB2 Connect Enterprise Edition version is 10.1 
I have used below command to catalog the z/os database.

```
db2 CATALOG TCPIP NODE <SampleNode> REMOTE <Server_Name> SERVER <Port_Number> 
db2 CATALOG DATABASE <Test_DB> AS <Test_DB> at NODE <SampleNode> AUTHENTICATION DCS 
db2 "catalog dcs db <Test_DB> as <Test_DB> parms ',,,,,,,,BIDI=856'"
```

And, I have tried with BIDI=424 also. Since HE_IL locale is supporting the utf-8 (1208), Shall I use BIDI=1208 when catalog the DCS directory. 
Thank You!!!

Comment: Usually character display issues are related to your terminal or the application program you're using to display the query results. Make sure you have Hebrew fonts installed, for example. I don't think this has much to do with DB2 per se.